# Git: Print 'git clone' output into a file & remove progress substate lines

Tags: git

I want to print the git clone output into a file.

The file should have the same content as the console output after terminating the process.

e.g.

```
Cloning into 'repo'...
remote: Counting objects: 8, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (6/6), done.
remote: Total 8 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
Receiving objects: 100% (8/8), done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (1/1), done.
Checking connectivity... done
```

This would be the desired output.

Unfortunately, I get subsequent lines for the singe progess states:

```
Cloning into 'repo'...
remote: Counting objects: 8, done.[K
remote: Compressing objects:  16% (1/6)   [K
remote: Compressing objects:  33% (2/6)   [K
remote: Compressing objects:  50% (3/6)   [K
remote: Compressing objects:  66% (4/6)   [K
remote: Compressing objects:  83% (5/6)   [K
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (6/6)   [K
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (6/6), done.[K
remote: Total 8 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)[K
Receiving objects:  12% (1/8)   
Receiving objects:  25% (2/8)   
Receiving objects:  37% (3/8)   
Receiving objects:  50% (4/8)   
Receiving objects:  62% (5/8)   
Receiving objects:  75% (6/8)   
Receiving objects:  87% (7/8)   
Receiving objects: 100% (8/8)   
Receiving objects: 100% (8/8), done.
Resolving deltas:   0% (0/1)   
Resolving deltas: 100% (1/1)   
Resolving deltas: 100% (1/1), done.
Checking connectivity... done
```

Is there a way to cope with that?

Comment: Your use of the word "bypass" is confusing, you aren't showing what you're doing - only that the result is not what you want.

Comment: well I think I did. Console output is desired as file output. Wrong file output is also shown. Bypass is confusing, accepted :)

Comment: `well I think I did.` there's nothing like this in the question "I ran `git clone x > path.to.file`" As should be evident from the answer below the options passed to clone are relevant; the exact command used to generate the output avoids any guesswork.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't care about the progress, you could redirect the output of:

```
git clone -q

--quiet
-q
```

> Operate quietly. **Progress is not reported to the standard error stream**.
>   This flag is also passed to the `rsync' command when given.

---

Update 3 years later: this option was not working well when cloning a repo *and* its submodules.
This is fixed with Git 2.14.x/2.15 (Q3 2017)

See [commit 03c004c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/03c004c581fb0ecd40bf21990449f393934b15ef) (03 Aug 2017) by [Brandon Williams (`mbrandonw`)](https://github.com/mbrandonw).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit cd2a952](https://github.com/git/git/commit/cd2a952458928ccef767cf3555601f07b07b2fb0), 22 Aug 2017)</sup>

> "`git clone --recurse-submodules --quiet`" did not pass the quiet
>   option down to submodules.

Comment: well, this would be nice if I could pass on the progress outcome. Unfortunately I need the last line (mostly 100% - on success) :/